# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas' (when running a linear regression)

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda

I am new to Python and I am trying to run a *linear regression* Python code, which I have downloaded.

My problem starts here

```py
import pandas as pd
```

When I run the code, it tells me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\MACHINE LEARNING\linear regression tutorial\free_python_tips-main\free_python_tips-main\04_linear_regression\04_linear_regression.py", line 9, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

although this package is installed, in Anaconda as well.

How could I solve this?

Comment: You probably ran a different version of python, maybe the system one? Try `pip install pandas` or make sure you run the python you install with anaconda.

Answer (score 2):

go to your command prompt and type
`pip install pandas`

or if you are using anaconda then type

```
conda install pandas
```

you can refer these links for more details:
[package installation with anaconda](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/packages/pkg-docs/) and
[pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/install.html)

and if you wanted to use Linear Regression then you need to install scikit learn

for pip

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

for anaconda

```
conda install -c conda-forge scikit-learn
```

then you need to import it in your code

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
```

Hope it solves your issue !!

Comment: Dear user,

unfortunately not. I launched Anaconda and it tells me that pandas is already installed (version 1.2.4). The same for the linear regression package. It is all installed and up to date but when I run the code, it does not work.

Comment: even if I launch pycharm from Anaconda, it gives me the same error

Comment: however, if I copy and paste the code on the python IDLE Shell 3.9.6, there's no problem. All the libraries are imported

Comment: everything works fine by using the IDLE consolle, except for the line                      
 df['fitted'] = model_lr.predict(df[['weight']]), which gives me the message               
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead.